# Which file stores data from an application in VB?

Tags: file, qbasic

I'm having trouble identifying and opening the file that contains the data of an application programmed in old VB.

I found in source code a subroutine that opens location and data upload files:

```
***** LOCATION SUBJECT AND LOADING TEST DATA *********
LOADING:
      GoSub ABREARQ
      If Val(BAKCP$) >= Val(NI$) And Val(BAKCP$) <= Val(NF$) Then
        GoSub LIMPA
      Else
        GoSub LIMPA
        Get #1, 1, GEALL: ORD1& = Val(GEALL.FB)
        EX& = 0
        Open Path$ + "NSALL.IND" For Random Shared As #5 Len = Len(NSALL)
        NR& = LOF(5) / Len(NSALL)
        If ORD1& > (NR& + 2) Then
          For IX& = ORD1& - 1 To NR& + 2 Step -1
           Get #1, IX&, GEALL
           If Val(BAKCP$) >= Val(GEALL.NI) And Val(BAKCP$) <= Val(GEALL.NF) Then
            EX& = IX&: IX& = NR& + 2
           End If
          Next
        End If
        If EX& = 0 Then
        BR& = 1: TR& = NR&
          Do Until (TR& < BR&)
             MR& = Int((TR& + BR&) / 2)
             Get #5, MR&, NSALL
             If Val(BAKCP$) >= NSALL.NSI And Val(BAKCP$) <= NSALL.NSF Then
                EX& = NSALL.RE
                Exit Do
             ElseIf Val(BAKCP$) > NSALL.NSI Then
                BR& = MR& + 1
             Else
                TR& = MR& - 1
             End If
          Loop
        End If
        Close #5

         If EX& <> 0 Then
         Get #1, EX&, GEALL
         FB$ = GEALL.FB: NI$ = GEALL.NI: NF$ = GEALL.NF: NP$ = GEALL.NP: NP0$ = GEALL.NP
         REGDT& = EX& - 1: REGRS& = Val(GEALL.RS)
         GoSub CARGADT
         MSG$ = ""
        Else
         For Y = 1 To 12: For X = 1 To DT%(0, Y): DT$(X, Y) = "": Next: Next
         FB$ = "": NI$ = "": NF$ = "": NP$ = "": NP0$ = ""
         REGDT& = 0: REGRS& = 0
         MSG$ = " N„o cadastrado/inex.! "
         BAKCP$ = "          ": Close: Return
        End If


      End If
```

Here is the routine that opens the files:

```
ABREARQ:
    Open Path$ + "GEALL.ENS" For Random Shared As #1 Len = Len(GEALL)
    Open Path$ + "DTALL.ENS" For Random Shared As #2 Len = Len(DTALL)
    Open Path$ + "RSALL.ENS" For Random Shared As #3 Len = Len(DR)
    Open Path$ + "CFALL.ENS" For Random Shared As #4 Len = 1080
    FIELD #4, 1075 AS CFALL$, 5 AS PROX$
    Return
```

I think the memory files are those with .ENS extension, but when I open them in text format, random and messy numbers appear.

Is there another way to open these ENS files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "old VB"  That is not VB.NET code and barely looks like VB6

Comment: I shudder to think what Option Explicit would do to that Module.

Comment: That looks like QBasic or GW-Basic to me.

Comment: But to address your question as to reading/opening the files - from the little bit of code you've provided, the file format would seem to be proprietary to this application, and it isn't in a human-readable format. So, no, there probably isn't 'another way' to open the files in order to easily make sense of them.

Comment: There is no indication of what the random record file structures GEALL, GTALL, and DR are being declared as.

Comment: The contents of random record files do not always represent anything as text.